# Toggle class on mouse-enter / mouse-leave in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have following element using ngFor

```
<span *ngFor="let picture of pictures; let i = index">
    <a target="_blank" href="{{picture.image}}" class="thumbnail-display image-overlay">
        <span class="overlay-icon hide">
            <i class="fa fa-file-image-o image-preview" [attr.data-url]="picture.image" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o image-del" aria-hidden="true" data-params="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;101&quot;, &quot;type&quot;:&quot;venue&quot;}" data-url="#"></i>
        </span>
        <img src="{{picture.thumb}}">
    </a>
</span>
```

I want to remove `hide` class in `<span class="overlay-icon hide">` on mouse enter event, and add back `hide` class on mouse leave event.

I tried the following

```
<span [ngClass]="class[i]" (mouseover)="class[i]='overlay-icon'" (mouseout)="class[i]='overlay-icon hide'">
```

It doesn't work, and throws me following error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Can someone point me on how can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What template parse error do you see?

Comment: Could you define a true/false property in your component? On mouseover/mouseout set that property to true or false? Then use either ngIf or hidden bound to that true/false property to hide/show your span?

Comment: It isn't template parse error, I have updated my code with error.

Comment: I assume that error is coming from `class[i]`. Do you have an array in your code called `[class]`? If not, when it tries to access the 0th element, it displays that error.

Comment: @DeborahK I want this to be applicable only on the element it hovers into. I have tried using the component variable approach, problem is, it gets applied to all element instead of single element it hovers into.

Comment: @DeborahK I got the hint. Initially I didn't define the array in called class. When I did, it works correctly for first time. The next time I hover it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do it without the array, by just remembering the index of the hovered span:

```
<a (mouseover)="hoverIdx = i" (mouseout)="hoverIdx = -1">
    <span [ngClass]="{ 'overlay-icon': true, 'hide': hoverIdx !== i }">
    </span>
</a>
```

That way you only need a variable `hoverIdx` that you initialize to -1 and you won't get array indexing problems. Also you don't have to create an array of the proper length and initialize it.

To avoid any flicker issues, place the hover handlers on the parent element, since the child gets toggled on/off.

> Here is a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-overlay-toggle-on-hover)

Comment: I tried this, and it flickers constantly on mouse hover. What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz? I'll make one to test and see what happens

Comment: Try with mouseenter instead of mouseover, also, I think mouseout should be mouseleave

Comment: Tried, and same result. It flickers

Comment: Ok I will make a stackblitz to better understand what is going on

Comment: If I hover the mouse pointer on the element, it keeps constantly toggling the hide class.

Comment: Here is a stackblitz, but I am not hiding the spans, just changing the color: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-class-toggle-on-hover

Comment: what is your hide class code ? do you set display to hide ?

Comment: Yes, it is a built-in bootstrap class, which sets display:none

Comment: If the element gets hidden, it will be impossible to hover on it to bring it back, this is why, when you fixed the array in your code it only worked the first time

Comment: Wow, the same code and it still flickers for me. I can see it is working for you. Wondering what is happening here.

Comment: It is the overlay element gets hidden with display:none class. I had been using the same logic with jQuery and it works pretty well.

Comment: Oh ok, can the hover be detected on the parent, the anchor tag?